# Getting error in Android Studio while using google maps api

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2023-12-26 16:27:25.370 15274-15367 Google Maps Android API com.example...     E  In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: strings/google_map_key
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 26:AE:EE:A9:3A:13:EB:66:08:19:09:D3:C2:5E:17:75:1D:FC:25:5C;com.example...

Building java mobile application in Android Studio. And using google map api. Yesterday I was getting "NullPointerException", program was not seeing my map. But today suddenly my map showed places and gave this error.

My main question is actually, why it is not seeeing my map sometimes. (api key is correct)

Comment: Hi Hilal, can you attach a screenshot of the error? And, the code snippet where it's giving the NullPointerException.

Comment: Did you follow what the error says? Like activate the Maps SDK for Android in the console of your project? And also please make sure that you have the correct SHA1 restriction. But since this is related to your credentials/project, I'd suggest that you [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support) for a better line of support.